# How to keep a Progress bar running, after a form CGI SUBMIT with JS (Back end Python server)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, cherrypy

I have a process that takes 5 minutes to generate a report and the user is left wondering what is going on, seeing nothing happening on the screen.  I am not using AJAX for submitting.

```
function par_makeHttpObject() {
    try {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (error) {}
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (error) {}
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (error) {}
    throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
```

Is there a way with jQuery to leave a Progressbar running faking that something is going on until the results come back.

On the back end I use Python with CherryPy.

Any help would be appreciated
DK

Comment: If you aren't using AJAX, then why are you using AJAX?

Comment: I thought that this was just plain vanilla HTTP/XML.  Clearly, I'm new at this.   Maybe I should edit the question, then?

Comment: XMLHTTPRequest is an ajax request, :) All you need is $("#myprogressbar").show(), then .hide() on complete.

Comment: Thank you Kevin...  I am new at this and I thought that the code needed some "AJAX references"?  Okay, I removed that "No AJAX solution" stipulation...

Comment: @KevinB Is there a progressbar plugin which corresponds to that jQuery command?

Comment: Nope, you could simply have `<div id="myprogressbar">i'm a progressbar</div>` and it would show and hide that div. Just stick a progressbar graphic in that div and position the div appropriately.

Comment: @KevinB  But will that progress bar be moving, simulating that something is going on???  I need that

Comment: If that's what you put inside of it, yes. YOu can put an animated GIF in it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

With @KevinB advice I solved the problem a little differently:

1.- I Created a "Progressbar.gif" picture to look like a bar I wanted

[image]

2.- I Added an image tag as follows:

```
<img id="progressbar1" height="6" src="/static/Progressbar.gif" style="position: relative; left:-273px; top:6px; width:0px;"/>
```

3.- And a tinny jQuery animation which sequences the effects giving the appearance of a process going on.

```
$("#progressbar1").animate({"width": "70px"}, 500,
        function() {$("#progressbar1").animate({"width": "350px"}, 800,
            function() {fetchExportReport(xpLoc,xpFunds,xpPcnt,reGen);
        });
```

And since the process takes some time, a little display of motion at the start might give enough confidence that it will complete after a while.

It is a compromise, but making an SQL query which takes a long time prevents comebacks to update the screen if progress is to be updated continuously.  So I had to compromise.  Some processes cannot be interrupted.

DK